# How to implement a MVC type (global) controller within a VB.Net (windows form) application?

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller

I am used to creating (Excel) VBA user form programs in a MVC style, and have recently been looking at VB.Net a bit more.

In general, I would create a MVC style user form application in VBA by creating an 'Initialize' function which creates an instance of a 'Controller' module and utilizes a 'LaunchProgram' method contained within this controller. This method would create an instance of the model and view used by the application, and then present the view to the user.

For example,

```
Public Sub Launch()
    With New Controller
        .Present
    End With
    Debug.Print "Execution ended"
End Sub
```

and then in the Controller (class) module I would have code such as

```
Private WithEvents m_View As View
Private m_Model As Model

Public Sub Present()
    Set m_View = New View
    Set m_Model = New Model
    m_View.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

My issue with VB.Net is that there is no obvious way to create an equivalent of the 'Launcher' sub, which controls the execution of the program, and instead just presents a default instance of the main form to the user upon running the program. I have attempted to replicate the desired architecture by creating a main form which is (supposed to be) immediately hidden upon starting the program. This hidden form (should) then create specific instances of all other forms, controlling how user input is processed and returned in accordance with the general MVC methodology.

However, this doesn't work since the VB.Net code...

```
Public mSetupForm As SetupForm
Public mOutputForm As OutputForm

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Debug.Print("Program initialized")
    mSetupForm = New SetupForm
    mOutputForm = New OutputForm
    Me.Hide()
    mSetupForm.Show()
End Sub
```

...does not hide Form1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, VB.NET applications use the mysterious **Windows Application Framework** which means that the build process adds an entry point for you which automatically runs whichever form you use as the main form. You can access these settings via **Project Properties > Application > Windows application framework properties**.

If you don't want to use the framework, un-check the **Enable application framework** check box and then select that you want to use **Sub Main** as your **Startup object**. Then you can create a module with a `Public Sub Main` method which will be the entry point to the application.

In the main, if you want to show a form, just call `Application.Run` and pass it the instance of the form you want to show (you can call it multiple times in succession if you want to).